# Как определять фигуры на изображении?

Tags: javascript, html, css, atom

Задача написать десктоп программу карту здания. Приложение пишется на html5/css/js на базе Atom-electron
[image: Карта]

Сейчас она стоит как `background`. Как распозновать фиигуры. Идея - сделать что-то типа Google Maps. По нажатию на область будет показываться краткая информация и путь от местонахождение терминала до области.

Comment: банальная работа с координатами?

Comment: @Jean-Claude если разрешение устройства будет менятся, не собъёются ли все координаты?

Comment: [map element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map)